# How to read jar from Android Private Libraries

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

I have an android app, In Android Private Libraries I have got jar files. I don't know how to open it for read. I searched but nothing works. The IDE is Eclipse Helios 3.6. 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Eclipse`, then

1)Copy the `JAR` file into your project in the `Libs` directory if it exist.

2)Create the `Libs` directory in not exist in your project.

3)Right click on the `JAR` file after coping it and select `Add to Build Path` from `Build Path` section.

4)Now, you can use it and import from it.

I hope it helps

Comment: I have libs folder. I make this 4 steps but still can't open to read (after point 3 IDE makes Referenced Libraries).

Comment: After adding the Library to your `Build path` you will be able to import any class from it in your Java class. Follow the library tutorial after that,